# Request Failed with status code 403, Access denied: Invalid token, wrong code

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to submit a project but i am not able to do it, I have checked similar questions on stack overflow but none of them have the solution.

I have to submit the project using POST method by providing Basic AUTH with username and TOTP generated password. Whenever I try to submit it I get the same issue every time I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here is my code

```
import { totp } from "otplib";
import axios from "axios";

const userId = "example@gmail.com";
const secret = "SECRETCODE";
const sharedSecret = userId + secret;

// JSON DATA
const reqBody = {
  {
  "github_url": "https://github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY",
  "contact_email": "YOUR_EMAIL"
}
};

const stringfyJSON = JSON.stringify(reqBody);

totp.options = { digits: 10, algorithm: "sha512", step: 30 };

const token = totp.generate(sharedSecret);
const isValid = totp.check(token, sharedSecret);
const isVerified = totp.verify({ token, secret: sharedSecret });


const credentials = Buffer.from(
  `${reqBody.contact_email}:${token}`,
  "utf-8"
).toString("base64");
const auth = `Basic ${credentials}`;
console.log(auth);
console.log(credentials);

const createReq = async () => {
  try {
    const config = {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: auth,
      },
    };
    console.log(
      "Making request to ",
      "REQURL"
    );

    await axios
      .post(
        "example@example.com",
        stringfyJSON,
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

createReq();
```

i have done all the research and everything but nothing seems to work.

**SAMPLE REQUEST**

```
POST /challenges/003 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic bmluamFAZXhhbXBsZS5jb206MTU5NTk0MjU2MA==
Host: api.example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 104

{"contact_email":"ninja@example.com", "github_url":"https://github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY"
```

Comment: Where is the token stored? Can't see it in your example

Comment: Token is generated using otplib

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem once but I figured out when using header you need to put "=" at the end like

```
Basic QXVYUVdTMHhMTmVCOXpKNjUzNTloOTVJZ0lDOndYaDNoNzlPNXdZbnJMVW5YNEo0QWFrZ2FveDY4akkyRVlQWGpWcUI0NWJtUnJuUW56dVNieWtVUDNYQ25pZzM=
```

So in you case

```
const auth = `Basic ${credentials}=`;
console.log(auth);
```

Comment: Tried this but not working still getting same error

Comment: Can you share console.log results?

Comment: do you want to see the complete error log or just console.log of auth

Comment: just console.log of auth.

Comment: `Basic aXphemFobTNkQGdtYWlsLmNvbSI6IjIwNTY5NzU5Mzg=`

Comment: You are missing ":" bertween email sercret or hash and token. Should be like 
Just assuming after kQ : is placed 
Basic aXphemFobTNkQ:GdtYWlsLmNvbSI6IjIwNTY5NzU5Mzg=

Comment: as i read on documentation i think the ":" should be used before encoding and i have done it the same way and if you'll look the sample request you'll see there is no ":" in encoded string

Comment: If you use : before encoding it will also encoded in some sort of other character in postman I have tried the same way as I told you it worked fine.